# How to programmatically find branches that were merged into master with git?

Tags: php, git

I'm trying to determine the best way to programmatically determine which branches have been recently merged into master. Ideally this script will run off a git hook, parsing the values and then do extra processing based on the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
git branch --merged
```

it will show you the list of branches merged.
I would use what ever script to start the process then you can extract what you want from it.